# ELKI PAM clustering

Tags: k-means, elki

I'm using ELKI for the first time and I'm having a problem understanding it's structure. It seems that I need to do a lot to produce some results.

How can I perform PAM K-medoid clustering with custom distance measure?

Answer (score 2):

1. Implement your distance function (see [this tutorial](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/wiki/Tutorial/DistanceFunctions))

   The section "**Basic distance function**" is a **minimal working example**. Add the `elki.jar`, create this class, run the project in eclipse, and you should be able to choose this distance function in PAM.
2. Make sure it has either

   - a `public`, *parameterless* constructor (easiest), **or**
   - a `public static class Parameterizer` (see documentation)

   so that it can be instantiated and configured by the GUI.
3. To make it appear in the UI dropdown, ensure it is either

   - in a *folder* on your classpath (development mode - just don't build a jar - easiest), **or**
   - in a `.jar`, and listed in the `META-INF/elki/<interfacename>` service file

   or type the class name. But usually there is a mistake in step 2 if it doesn't show up in the dropdown; and the class cannot be instantiated.
4. Run PAM and choose your distance function in the dropdown.

The most common mistake is that people don't have a constructor the UI could use.

The constructor *must* be `public` and parameterless, or you need to add a parameterizer to specify the parameters.